# Execute Asynchronous Task before Electron Window Closes

Tags: javascript, electron, web-worker

I have an electron application, running Angular for the UI in a BrowserWindow. The Angular application starts a web-worker, which opens up a websocket connection to an external application. I'd like to send a particular message across the websocket before my application closes, to signal the external application to close as well.

Right now, I'm using the beforeunload event in the UI (in an Angular service):

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {

    // Simplified version of sending the shutdown command
    this.webWorker.postMessage("shutdown");

});
```

The worker responds (in a separate thread) to this command by immediately sending the shutdown command over websocket.

This introduces a race condition - which will happen first? The browser window closing and killing the web-worker? Or the web-worker sending the websocket message in a separate thread? Often during development it's the latter, but during production with optimized code it seems to be the former (but not consistently).

So fundamentally my problem is that the beforeunload hook can't wait for an asynchronous task to complete, so I can't set it up to wait until the external application has confirmed it's received the websocket command.

Some things I've considered:

1. use the electron main process instead - this would solve the race condition, but it does not have access to the websocket.
2. put in a for loop after the "postMessage" call - this works most of the time, but boy does it not feel like a good approach.
3. async/await - beforeunload doesn't care about async await, it moves right along and the window closes.
4. window.alert() and the like - they don't seem to appear, and even if they did work I don't want to bother the user when they close the window.

My question - how can I ensure that the websocket message is sent by the worker prior to my Electron UI window exiting? Are there different hooks/notifications I should be using to accomplish this?

Comment: Can't you simply listen for the onclose wvent on the other side? What about a beacon system? If the receiver doesn't receive a new message in x seconds consider it closed.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion - the websocket connection should not drop until shutdown, so this could work. I'd be happy to accept an answer along these lines.